# CUPS server taking a long time to print certain jobs

Tags: printing, network-printer, cups, print-server

I have a CUPS server set up, to which Windows machines can print. Everything seems to work well (Microsoft Office and some other programs I've tried), except for Adobe Acrobat Pro. It takes a long time -- sometimes some 40 minutes -- before print jobs are successfully executed.

I set the CUPS LogLevel to Debug, and I observe that these are always the last couple lines before it hangs:

```
...
D [25/May/2012:15:09:24 -0700] cupsdSetBusyState: Not busy
D [25/May/2012:15:09:24 -0700] cupsdReadClient: 12 POST /printers/printer HTTP/1.1
D [25/May/2012:15:09:24 -0700] cupsdSetBusyState: Active clients
D [25/May/2012:15:09:24 -0700] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [25/May/2012:15:09:24 -0700] cupsdReadClient: 12 1.0 Print-Job 2
```

After that last line, nothing happens for a while.

Nothing, that is, except for these lines, repeated over and over again:

```
D [25/May/2012:15:15:03 -0700] Report: clients=1
D [25/May/2012:15:15:03 -0700] Report: jobs=72
D [25/May/2012:15:15:03 -0700] Report: jobs-active=0
D [25/May/2012:15:15:03 -0700] Report: printers=2
D [25/May/2012:15:15:03 -0700] Report: printers-implicit=0
D [25/May/2012:15:15:03 -0700] Report: stringpool-string-count=8555
D [25/May/2012:15:15:03 -0700] Report: stringpool-alloc-bytes=11344
D [25/May/2012:15:15:03 -0700] Report: stringpool-total-bytes=163552
D [25/May/2012:15:15:15 -0700] cupsdNetIFUpdate: "lo" = localhost:631
D [25/May/2012:15:15:15 -0700] cupsdNetIFUpdate: "eth0" = <server-ip>:631
D [25/May/2012:15:15:15 -0700] cupsdNetIFUpdate: "lo" = localhost:631
D [25/May/2012:15:15:15 -0700] cupsdNetIFUpdate: "eth0" = <server-ip>%eth0:631
```

These keep repeating until some arbitrary (and varying) amount of time later, when I see these lines, and the document starts printing soon.

```
D [25/May/2012:15:15:35 -0700] Print-Job http://<server-ip>:631/printers/printer
D [25/May/2012:15:15:35 -0700] [Job ???] Auto-typing file...
I [25/May/2012:15:15:35 -0700] [Job ???] Request file type is application/postscript.
D [25/May/2012:15:15:35 -0700] cupsdMarkDirty(----J-)
...
```

Printing from Microsoft Word produces no such hang, however:

```
...
D [25/May/2012:14:17:25 -0700] cupsdReadClient: 17 1.0 Print-Job 2
D [25/May/2012:14:17:25 -0700] Print-Job http://<server-ip>:631/printers/printer
...
```

Wireshark and tcpdump indicate that communication is occurring at all times, however.

Would you have any ideas regarding how I might resolve this issue?

**EDIT**

I printed essentially the same document again. This time, I observed something different before the hang:

```
D [25/May/2012:15:50:02 -0700] cupsdReadClient: 17 POST /printers/printer HTTP/1.1
D [25/May/2012:15:50:02 -0700] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [25/May/2012:15:50:02 -0700] cupsdReadClient: 17 1.0 Print-Job 2
D [25/May/2012:15:50:02 -0700] cupsdReadClient: 21 1.0 Get-Jobs 10
D [25/May/2012:15:50:02 -0700] Get-Jobs http://<server-ip>:631/printers/printer
D [25/May/2012:15:50:02 -0700] Returning IPP successful-ok for Get-Jobs (http://<server-ip>:631/printers/printer) from <client-ip>
D [25/May/2012:15:50:23 -0700] Report: clients=4
D [25/May/2012:15:50:23 -0700] Report: jobs=73
D [25/May/2012:15:50:23 -0700] Report: jobs-active=0
D [25/May/2012:15:50:23 -0700] Report: printers=2
...
D [25/May/2012:15:54:23 -0700] Report: stringpool-alloc-bytes=11376
D [25/May/2012:15:54:23 -0700] Report: stringpool-total-bytes=167048
D [25/May/2012:15:54:30 -0700] Closing client 12 after 300 seconds of inactivity...
D [25/May/2012:15:54:30 -0700] cupsdCloseClient: 12
D [25/May/2012:15:54:30 -0700] Closing client 13 after 300 seconds of inactivity...
D [25/May/2012:15:54:30 -0700] cupsdCloseClient: 13
D [25/May/2012:15:54:40 -0700] cupsdNetIFUpdate: "lo" = localhost:631
D [25/May/2012:15:54:40 -0700] cupsdNetIFUpdate: "eth0" = <server-ip>:631
...
D [25/May/2012:15:55:23 -0700] Report: stringpool-total-bytes=167048
D [25/May/2012:15:55:32 -0700] Print-Job http://<server-ip>:631/printers/printer
D [25/May/2012:15:55:32 -0700] [Job ???] Auto-typing file...
I [25/May/2012:15:55:32 -0700] [Job ???] Request file type is application/postscript.
D [25/May/2012:15:55:32 -0700] cupsdMarkDirty(----J-)
...
```

The file came out of the printer at 15:56, but this seems to be by far the largest part of the delay.

**EDIT 2**

I should note that printing to an XPS file from Adobe Acrobat, and then printing to the CUPS server printer from the *XPS file* produces no such delay. So it would appear that it is Adobe Acrobat that's the culprit.

**SOLUTION**

I finally solved the problem by choosing a non-generic postscript driver for the printer (in Windows).

Comment: what version of Adobe Acrobat Pro exhibits this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the size of the print-file that is generated by Adobe Acrobat?

If very large compared to Word, this could explain the delay.

Comment: Well, the PDF being opened by Adobe Acrobat is 189.8 KB in size, and I'm only printing 1 or 2 pages of the document at a time, so size shouldn't be a concern here. I've printed entire webpages with photos and everything from Internet Explorer just fine. See my second edit -- the same thing printed from XPS viewer prints just fine.

Comment: You say that the same file prints much faster in other applications, and that it is only Adobe that creates slow print jobs. So it must be doing something wasteful, creating a print file that takes too long to process. There are many ways to encode a pdf in postscript - so it would be well to find out what file does Adobe actually produce. I can't check that for you, since I don't have your environment.

Comment: ... See also this article : [Optimizing PDFs with Adobe Acrobat](http://layersmagazine.com/optimizing-pdfs-with-adobe-acrobat.html). I wonder if this will have any impact on the print speed.

Comment: Aha. I'll try that out when I get back to the CUPS server tomorrow or something. How would you find the produced Adobe Acrobat file? I'm running Adobe Acrobat on Windows 7 32-bit.

Comment: I don't have a cups server to play with, but looking at [cupsd.conf(5)](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.5/man-cupsd.conf.html), the directory for these files might be in the DataDir path directive, by default /usr/share/cups. Once you know what Adobe produces and how it differs from Word, you might also need to look at your configured [filters](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/man-filter.html).

Comment: Hm, I didn't see anything in that folder. Interestingly, when I tried printing from Adobe Acrobat on a Windows 7 64 bit machine, it worked just fine....

Comment: (anything that looked interesting in that folder, I should say)

Comment: Nevermind, I finally solved the problem by choosing a non-generic postscript driver for the printer. Thanks for the help though!